# B-cycle integral with multi-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-integrals

Hy, I would like some help with my integral :
$
\oint_B\frac{1}{z^2}\sqrt{(z-a)(z+\bar{a})(z-\frac{1}{a})(z+\frac{1}{\bar{a}})}
$

Where B is the contour that connect the two branch cuts associated to my square root. And moreover, I know that the points z=1 and z=-1 belong to my two branch cuts.

I naively tried to compute half of the integral by choosing one branch of my multi-valued function : ( by putting $z=e^{-i\theta}$ from 0 to $\pi$):

\begin{eqnarray}
    \int^{\pi}_{0}d\theta\sqrt{(2\cos{\theta}-A)(2\cos{\theta}+\bar{A})}
\end{eqnarray}
Where $A=a+\frac{1}{a}$

Then by changing the variable $u=\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}$ :

\begin{eqnarray}
    = 4\int^{1}_{0}du \sqrt{\frac{(1-2u^2-\frac{A}{2})(1-2u^2+\frac{\bar{A}}{2})}{1-u^2}}
\end{eqnarray}

Then $v=1-2u^2$ :
\begin{eqnarray}
    =-4\int^{-1}_1dv\frac{1}{4\sqrt{(\frac{1-v}{2})(\frac{1+v}{2})}}\sqrt{(v-\frac{A}{2})(v+\frac{\bar{A}}{2})}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
    = -2\int^{-1}_1dv\sqrt{\frac{(v-\alpha)(v+\bar{\alpha})}{(1-v)(1+v)}}
\end{eqnarray}
where $\alpha=\frac{A}{2}$

But since $\alpha$ is complex, I didn't find a way to express to espress it using elliptic functions. I have two questions :

1. Does any one know how to compute this kind of integral, that connects two branch cuts ? I'm a physicist, I'm not quite familiar with Riemann surfaces etc ..
2. If my naive approach is correct, does anyone know how to simplify my last expression ?

Any help or even a reference would be very helpful !

Here is the kind of cycle I want to compute : [B-cycle integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxDOk.png)

Thanks